# Remove Registered OAuth Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

Using the new MVC 4 templates for OpenAuth, does anyone know if registered clients can be removed after they've been added?

Clients are usually registered at start up. However, this doesn't have to be the case; you can register them whenever you want. I'm working on a module that allows for the built-in clients to be registered at any time (which works), but I can't seem to find a way to remove a registered client without forcing a restart of the website.

Does the API allow for this without restarting the site?